# Problem in drawing a scatterplot in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm drawing a scatterplot using seaborn and here is my code for that

```
sns.scatterplot(x="avg_PE_train",
                 y="sale_log",
                 hue="ARTCL_DESC",
                 legend = False,
                 s = 300,
                 data = df)
```

`df` is my pandas dataframe and has all the necessary columns. I'm trying to use the columns which have double values to determine the size of the dots in the graph (as opposed to a fixed size which I currently have here), but when I make that change (replace 300 with "column_name") it does not show any dots and basically shows an empty graph.

Comment: `s = df['column_name']`?

Answer (score 0):

`scatterplot` has a parameter [`size=`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html?highlight=scatterplot#seaborn.scatterplot) that you can use to have the size of the points be proportional to the values in a column

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", size="size",
                     data=tips)
```

[image]